# Program to count program sizes

Tags: c#, size, lines-of-code

I have to Write a program (in C#) to count (in LOC) the 
• total program size 
• total size of each of the program’s parts (classes, functions, or procedures) 
• the number of items (or methods) in each part.

Produce and print 
• a single count for the entire program 
• size and item counts for each part together with the part name

But I really don't know how to do it.

Any idea?

Comment: You could use a Regular Expression.

Comment: Homework? You should at least say what you've tried, but here's a hint: read each line, determine if it's a "LOC" or not. You'll need to track things like the start and end of comments. For methods, you'll need to track how deeply nested the curly braces are (+1 for every {, -1 for every }, when you reach 0, you've ended a method).

Comment: Determining what constitutes a line of code is also a problem. Does a curly brace by itself count? Do you include or exclude comments (arguably comments are as valuable as code, don't want to discourage leaving comments).

Comment: To add to @GaryWalker said, what about code that's broken down into multiple lines? Is that one line of code, or multiple?

Comment: Hey guys, thank you. You helped me so much. I defined all these things about "{s" and "/* */", LOC, and more in a code standard.


My app now count the total Lines Of Code, and blocks (starting with "{" and finishing with "}")

**But what about the number of items (or methods) in each part, Produce and print a single count for the entire program, and produce and print size and item counts for each part together with the part name?**

How could I do it?
I don't understand